# Pythonic way of converting 'None' string to None

Tags: python, yaml, nonetype

Let's say I have the following yaml file and the value in the 4th row should be `None`. How can I convert the string `'None'` to `None`?

```
CREDENTIALS:
  USERNAME: 'USERNAME'
  PASSWORD: 'PASSWORD'
LOG_FILE_PATH: None <----------
```

I already have this:

```
config = yaml.safe_load(open(config_path, "r"))
username, password, log_file_path = (config['CREDENTIALS']['USERNAME'],
                                     config['CREDENTIALS']['PASSWORD'],
                                     config['LOG_FILE_PATH'])
```

I would like to know if there is a pythonic way to do this, instead of simply doing:

```
if log_file_path == 'None':
  log_file_path = None
```

Comment: I like your solution. Maybe ``log_file_path = None if log_file_path == 'None' else xxx`` is shorter but it's just your solution rewritten. Don't be tempted to make ``eval(log_file_path)`` :-)

Comment: Your solution is fine. You could make it a one-liner but that may obscure it more: `log_file_path = log_file_path if not log_file_path == 'None' else None`

Comment: I agree with @MSeifert. According to the zen of Python, explicit is better than implicit, and your solution seems to me quite Pythonic. I even find your original formulation much clearer than Dan's.

Comment: In the config file you could leave LOG_FILE_PATH: without a value and config['LOG_FILE_PATH'] would be None.

Comment: Use `null`, not `None`, in the YAML file.

Comment: Nice solutions! Both leaving it blank and using `null` work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `None` value in your YAML file is not really kosher YAML since YAML it uses absence of a value to represent None. So if you just used proper YAML your troubles would be over:

```
In [7]: yaml.load("""
   ...: CREDENTIALS:
   ...:   USERNAME: 'USERNAME'
   ...:   PASSWORD: 'PASSWORD'
   ...: LOG_FILE_PATH: 
   ...: """)
Out[7]: 
{'CREDENTIALS': {'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD', 'USERNAME': 'USERNAME'},
 'LOG_FILE_PATH': None}
```

Notice how it read the absence of the `LOG_FILE_PATH` as `None` rather than `'None'`.

Later edit: Other values which also work are: `null`, `Null` and `NULL` as per: https://yaml.org/type/null.html

Comment: Great solution @Oin. It is more of a matter of adjusting the YAML file rather than making it more Pythonic. One suggestion would be to also mention that `null` is another way of representing `None` in YAML, as someone said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022 the accepted answer does not work anymore:

```
import yaml

yaml.load("""
CREDENTIALS:
USERNAME: 'USERNAME'
PASSWORD: 'PASSWORD'
LOG_FILE_PATH: 
""")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/copo/.local/share/virtualenvs/CryptoBot-p2Vb7LJp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-30-0a9e2c21b3eb>", line 3, in <cell line: 3>
    yaml.load("""
TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
```

To have `None` for empty fields in the yaml file, the `yaml.FullLoader` has to be passed to the `yaml.load` function. As such:

```
import yaml

yaml.load("""
CREDENTIALS:
USERNAME: 'USERNAME'
PASSWORD: 'PASSWORD'
LOG_FILE_PATH: null
""", yaml.FullLoader)

Out[32]: 
{'CREDENTIALS': None,
 'USERNAME': 'USERNAME',
 'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
 'LOG_FILE_PATH': None}
```

Note: the FullLoader can also handle `null` as `None` as shown above.